# Broadcast Receiver not correctly grabbing text message contents

Tags: android, text, sms, broadcastreceiver, android-manifest

I am creating an application that will grab the contents of a text message and display it in a pop up.  My Broadcast receiver is not shooting when a text message is received.

**Broadcast Receiver class**

```
public class SMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        Object[] pdus = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
        SmsMessage[] msgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

        /** sms sender phone */
        String smsSender = "";

        /** body of received sms */
        String smsBody = "";

        /** timerstamp */
        long timestamp = 0L;

        for (int i = 0; i < msgs.length; i++) {
            msgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
            smsSender += msgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
            smsBody += msgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            timestamp += msgs[i].getTimestampMillis();

        }
        intent.putExtra("sender", smsSender);
        intent.putExtra("body", smsBody);
        intent.putExtra("timestamp", timestamp);
    }

}
```

**Dialog Activity**
    public class PopSMSActivity extends Activity {

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        showDialog();
    }

    private void showDialog() {
        final String sms_sender = getIntent().getStringExtra("sender");
        final String sms_body = getIntent().getStringExtra("body");
        final long timestamp = getIntent().getLongExtra("timestamp", 0L);
        final String display = sms_sender + "\n" + sms_body + "\n" + timestamp;
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setMessage(display)
                .setCancelable(false)
                .setPositiveButton("Reply",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // reply by calling SMS program
                                smsReply(sms_sender, sms_body);
                            }
                        })
                .setNegativeButton("Close",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                                // go back to the phone home screen
                                goHome();
                            }
                        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
        alert.show();
    }

    private void smsReply(String sender, String body) {
        Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        sendIntent.putExtra("address", sender);
        sendIntent.putExtra("sms_body", body);
        sendIntent.setType("vnd.android-dir/mms-sms");
        startActivity(sendIntent);
        this.finish(); // close this Activity now
    }

    private void goHome() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(intent);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name="com.example.intereceptsms.SMSReceiver" >
            <intent-filter
                android:exported="true"
                android:priority="999" >
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity
            android:name="com.example.intereceptsms.PopSMSActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

</manifest>
```

I am not pulling up any errors, so there must be something that I am missing, any help will be great.  Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My Broadcast receiver is not shooting when a text message is received

That is because it is not doing anything, other than creating an `Intent`, which it then ignores. Presumably, your plan is to start `PopSMSActivity`, in which case you need the `startActivity()` call.

Also note that, while this is fine for experimentation, users may get very irritated if something takes over the foreground just because a text message arrived.

Comment: Yes, I completely forgot.  I know that this isn't a good practice, but I have something else in mind.  Thank You.